# Check if one vector contains at least one value from another vector

Tags: clojure

If I have two vectors:

```
(def moo [:a :b :c :d])

(def foo [:a :z :d :e :f :g])
```

what is the easiest (canonical) way to check whether moo contains at least one value which is also in foo. In this case it would return 'true' because :a and :d appear in foo.

And secondly: Is it possible to refine this further to return true iff foo contains all elements of moo (but is allowed to contain others as well)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i would simply do this:

for the first question:

`(some (set moo) foo)`

if finds the first item of `foo` which is present in `moo`

for the second one:

`(every? (set foo) moo)`

checks that every item of `moo` is contained by `foo`

Answer (score 2):

This will return a boolean telling you if you've got shared elements or not:

```
(empty? (clojure.set/intersection (set moo) (set foo)))
```

This will tell you if the intersection set contains all of the items in moo:

```
(= (count moo) (count (clojure.set/intersection (set moo) (set foo))))
```

Answer (score 1):

moo contains one element in foo:

```
(seq (clojure.set/intersection (set moo) (set foo)))
```

foo contains all elements of moo:

```
(empty? (clojure.set/difference (set moo) (set foo)))
```